# Can the suggestions from a suggest box in GWT be split into separate group/categories?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a suggest box which contains 2 types of suggestions. Lets say suggestion type `A` and suggestion type `B`.

I'd like to be able to split the displayed suggestions into 2 sub lists within the suggestions  so that all of the `A` type suggestions are grouped together and all the `B` types suggestions are grouped separately.

I haven't seen anything in `SuggestBox` or `SuggestOracle` that would permit me to do this? It seems that it's something that should be supported.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SuggestBox`'s default display of suggestions is a `MenuBar` in a `PopupPanel`, but you can provide [your own display](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.SuggestionDisplay.html) that would split `A`s and `B`s apart and display them in two lists, or however you'd like to display them.

Comment: Thanks! It's a little more work than I thought it would be but this will work.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my quick proposal, it's untested but maybe it will get you on the right track:

1. Create your own `SuggestOracle`, it's probably best to extend `MultiWordSuggestOracle`
2. Make sure to override `isDisplayStringHTML` to return true (but watch out for the usual threats when injecting values as HTML - XSS, etc.)
3. Add a new `add` method that will take the previous suggestion, modify it so that it includes some HTML/CSS code that will render the end of the previous group of suggestions.

Some pseudocode:

```
MyOracle oracle = new MyOracle();
oracle.add(suggestion1); // Group A
oracle.add(suggestion2);
oracle.newSuggestionGroup(); // insert, for example, <hr /> to the previous suggestion string, in this case suggestion2 - make sure to parse it away afterwards
oracle.add(suggestion3); // Group B
```

Comment: That's a good idea but the problem is that if the last suggestion of Group A isn't in the current list of suggestions then the separation isn't there anymore. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Then add the separator as a special `Suggestion` - one that returns an empty string in `getReplacementString`, but a `<hr />` like code in `getDisplayString`. ...and somehow always include it in the list of suggestions ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is using a third party library build on GWTQuery - http://jdramaix.github.com/gwtchosen/

You can also try hacking up SuggestBox or ListBox in GWT but they cannot be brought up to a nice polished gui level as in GwtChosen.

Comment: Bah, beat me to it ;) Your solution is clearly... clearer ;) And more polished - but hey, maybe someone wants to do some hacking, so I'll leave mine too :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was really hoping to stay away from 3rd party libraries though.